# HighCharts: How to combine custom colors with gradient

Tags: javascript, colors, highcharts, radial-gradients

For some while now Im playing with coloring of my pie chart... And either I got my custom colors without gradient, or default colors with gradient... My colors are stored in php field, which I want to load like `colors: <?echo $myColors;?>` .
Actual state of my code is like this (it shows default colors with gradient):

```
colors: Highcharts.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function(color) {
    return {
        radialGradient: { cx: 0.5, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
        stops: [
                [0, color],
                [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
        ]
    };
})
```

How should I edit it so it would show my own colors in simple way? Also I didn´t find what is "stops" option for...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use your colors in `map` instead of Highcharts built-in ones:

```
colors: Highcharts.map(<?echo $myColors;?>, function(color) {
    return {
        radialGradient: { cx: 0.5, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
        stops: [
                [0, color],
                [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
        ]
    };
})
```

Comment: One small flaw....When I click on some slice, the color of first 3 slices suddenly changes back to the default...I tried to reproduce this in jsFiddle, but there it works correctly...Do you have any idea, what can be causing this? My array looks like this: $myColors = array('#199ED5','#77CC6D','#F136AD','#FF954E','#FFCC00','#00FFFF','#FF0000','#66FF00','#660099');

Comment: SOLVED! The number of colors changed actually equals the number of slices (colors) displayed by the second chart (which is set to default colors at this moment)... So I think after I set my own color theme to the second chart, this problem dissapears.

Comment: Also note, I was using color names just for testing ('red', 'green', 'yellow'), instead of hex values, and it doesn't work... So if you are hitting your head up against the wall, make sure you are using hex color values here.

Comment: It is even more - only hex format (#XXXXXX) is supported in that case. Names ('red') or rgb(a) ( 'rgb(255,0,0)' or rgba(255,0,0,0.5) ) aren't.

Comment: Can you give an example of the format the data is supposed to be in? I mean can you paste an example of what `<?echo $myColors; ?>` actually returns?

Comment: Ignore my dumb comment. I could just do this to figure it out: `console.log(Highcharts.getOptions().colors)`