# Highcharts: Radial gradient not showing on custom chart

Tags: highcharts, radial-gradients

So I am trying to implement radial gradients with my custom pie chart.
I am using my own colors instead of the default colors.

I tried to implement the custom colors as seen in this thread:

[HighCharts: How to combine custom colors with gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14851418/highcharts-how-to-combine-custom-colors-with-gradient)

But I think with my data object I need to implement them in a different way.

I have an example of my chart located here:
http://jsfiddle.net/PcX4b/2/

Here is my code before calling the chart:

```
    data = [
    {
        color: "#61A6EC",
        name: "Equities",
        y: 40.07
    },{
        color: "#CC2A2A",
        name: "Cash",
        y: 30
    },{
        color: "#FFC448",
        name: "Options",
        y: 11.55
    },{
        color: "#ADD54D",
        name: "Fixed Income",
        y: 0.18
    },{
        color: "#FD8645",
        name: "Other",
        y: 0.00001
    }
];

var colors =[];     
var innerData = [];
var outerData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var brightness = 0.1;
    // inner circle
    innerData.push({
        name: data[i].name,
        y: data[i].y,
        color: data[i].color
    });
    // outer circle
    outerData.push({
        name: data[i].name,
        y: data[i].y,
        color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)'
    });
    colors.push(data[i].color);
}
    colors: Highcharts.map(colors, function(color) {
return {
    radialGradient: { cx: 0.5, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
    stops: [
            [0, color],
            [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
    ]
};
```

})

In there you can see the chart is rendering but I dont see any gradient. Not sure what I am doing wrong and I am not getting any errors so I am confused on why this isnt working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use  `Highcharts.getOptions().colors` and addign new color sby map() function, please take look at example below:

http://jsfiddle.net/CkKDy/1/

Comment: I added that and it still doesnt seem to be showing a gradient.
http://jsfiddle.net/PcX4b/3/

Comment: But what is wrong with my example which has gradients and yours colors?

Comment: I must be missing something. I implemented Highcharts.getOptions().colors but it still isnt working with my chart. I really think something else needs to be set or turned on maybe?

Can you see this chart? jsfiddle.net/PcX4b/3

Answer (score 0):

try to use manually setting property 'color' with object containing properties radialGradient and stops

```
color:{radialGradient:...,stops:...}
```

yes it should be working. checked a minute ago

Comment: So I tried that here:
http://jsfiddle.net/PcX4b/2/
and I get all these errors. Are you sure this is possible? Can you send me a jsfiddle of it working with the fiddle I just posted?